# Find an $a(z)>0$ such that $an^{z+1} \geq (an+a-1)(n+1)^z$ holds for all $z\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Find a real number $a(z)>0$ such that $an^{z+1} \geq (an+a-1)(n+1)^z$ holds for all $z\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The value of $a$ is only allowed to be dependent of $z$.
This seems rather hard since $z$ only appears as an exponent.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this inequality for $a$?

Comment: @HansEngler I did, but I don't see how this helps me

Answer (score 0):

From $a \leqslant \frac{(n+1)^z}{(n+1)^{z+1}-n^{z+1}} \tag 1$ what if $n \to \infty$?

Try a few $z \in \mathbb N$ if you want to get an idea.

Also note that if $a_0>0$ is such a number, then any positive $a$ less than $a_0$ is also a solution.